# how to find, update and get back object collection in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

how to get the object back in Laravel when find and update, not just an integer?

```
$updatedCompProd = CompanyProduct::where('subscription_id', $stripeSub->id)
   ->update([
             'subscription_status'=>2,
             'subscription_end_datetime'=>Carbon::parse($stripeSub->current_period_end)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
]);
```

*$updatedCompProd is an integer of value 1*

Comment: You may use two separate way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first issue you can use Laravel `tap()` helper function like so

```
tap(CompanyProduct::where('subscription_id', $stripeSub->id)->first(), function (CompanyProduct $companyProduct) use ($stripeSub) {
   $companyProduct->update([
       'subscription_status'=>2,
       'subscription_end_datetime'=>Carbon::parse($stripeSub->current_period_end)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
   ]);
});
```

it will return the updated object, you can read about [Tap](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-tap)

**Another Solution**

```
$updatedCompProd = CompanyProduct::where('subscription_id', $stripeSub->id)->first();

$updatedCompProd->update([
             'subscription_status'=>2,
             'subscription_end_datetime'=>Carbon::parse($stripeSub->current_period_end)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
]);

dd($updatedCompProd); // it will work also,
```

Comment: I can't believe we can't update a record and getting it back without making some juggling moves 

Comment: I have posted another simpler solution.